# javac activation error for windows 10 command prompt

Tags: java, javac

After installing JAVA SE & setting the environment variables this message is showing in command prompt " 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Did you open a new command prompt to update the environment? What variables did you add/modify?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\bin  These are the directories I have added @obermillerk

Comment: ... added to what?

Comment: Advanced System Settings> environment variables>Path @obermillerk

Comment: Okay, did you open a new command prompt after doing this or have you had the same one open?

Comment: Ok. Resolved. Thanks @obermillerk